# Instantiating a class by passing self as argument

Tags: python, oop

I came across some python examples where a class instance is created by Invoking the class and passing "self" to it. I cant seem to understand the meaning of it and when we would use such constructs.

Below is a sample extract, where a class is instantiated inside another class. I "think" I have also seen something like `objA = Class_def(self)`. I cant recall where I saw that, so it would be good to know if its possible or not.

```
class BaseState(object):

    def __init__(self, protocol):
        self.protocol = protocol
    
    def connect(self, request):
        state = self.__class__.__name__



class IdleState(BaseState):

    def connect(self, request):
        return self.protocol.doConnect(request)



class ConnectingState(BaseState):

    def handleCONNACK(self, response):
        self.protocol.handleCONNACK(response)



class ConnectedState(BaseState):


    def disconnect(self, request):
        self.protocol.doDisconnect(request)


class BaseProtocol(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory):

    ###    
    # what is happening here -
    ###

        self.IDLE        = IdleState(self)
        self.CONNECTING  = ConnectingState(self)
        self.CONNECTED   = ConnectedState(self)
        self.state       = self.IDLE
```

Comment: `self` in class refers to the class object. lets say a class has a variable called **name**, `self.name = something`. while when we create an instance of that object, let's say it's **X**, `self.name` will become `X.name` while targeting object **X**.
you can read more about it [link here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. But that was not my question, I am asking what `self.IDLE        = IdleState(self)` this line does?

Comment: in your example `self.IDLE ` will take it's value from the method called `IdleState` while passing the object itself as a parameter of that method

Comment: You generally don't pass explicitly pass `self` when creating an instance of a class. However all methods of the class will have the current instance passed to them via an argument usually given that name.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, class is always passed to its method as an argument, this is the way they work. Although in e.x. C++ it is implicit, Python does that explicitly.

In BaseProtocol you are initializing members of `BaseProtocol` class. When initializing, `self` is redundant because constructor of IdleState method doesn't need access to its instance variables, so you can delete it. However if you are doing something with member `IDLE`, like calling method which is using its instance variables, you need to pass `self`.

Learn more:
https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/programming/self-variabe-python-examples

Answer (score -1):

It is absolutely possible to do that, as `self` is a default object passed by python -

```
class a:
  def __init__(self,__self,x):
    self.x=x
    print(self.x) #the local x that is passed into the object
    print(__self.x) #the x that is in the self that is passed into the object

class b:
  def __init__(self,x):
    self.x=x
    obj=a(self,'foo')

obj=b('baz') #should print 'foo', then 'baz'
```